# Cypress times out after making a POST request

Tags: javascript, java, http, cypress, end-to-end

My page contains a form in which the user can enter their name:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="nameSubmitted()">
  <input id="nameField" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="username">
  <input id="nameSubmitButton" type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

In Cypress I do:

```
cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/my-page-name.html');

cy.get('[id="nameField"]')
.type(my-test-username);

cy.get('[id="nameSubmitButton"]')
.click();
```

The intended behaviour is that the server associates the given username to the current session, and the user stays on the same page, with the `nameSubmitted()` function showing and hiding some DOM elements. This works fine when doing manual testing with a regular instance of Firefox, Chrome, Opera, or Brave, but fails when Cypress tries the same thing in Electron or Firefox (I haven't been able to add other browsers to Cypress, but that's a separate problem).

The server is the first HTTP server I've written, so I'm not 100% confident its behaviour is correct, but I can't find anything wrong. It's written in Java using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` and the associated classes, and I've tried two different responses to the POST request:

1. `204` No Content

On the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange` instance, I call:

```
aHttpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(204, -1);
aHttpExchange.getResponseBody().close();
```

This causes Cypress to get stuck waiting for the page to load, until it times out after 60 seconds. There is in fact nothing new that it should be loading, and the image of the page on the right of Cypress's browser instance shows that the page is displaying correctly (the `nameSubmitted()` function has correctly modified the DOM). I also see on the server that the POST request is successful and the username is set.

2. `200` OK

Just as a guess, I tried instead setting

```
aHttpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
```

and sending an empty string down the OutputStream before closing it. This causes Cypress (and normal browsers when not in test mode) to set this empty string as the page content, so that's no good.

According to the [http spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5):

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.

So it seems as though my server should be doing the right thing with response (1).

Does anybody know why the timeout occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this with help from user `jorrit-wehelp` at https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress.

The default form submission mechanism is now disabled by putting `onsubmit="return false;"` in each form element:

```
<form id="nameForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input id="nameField" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
  <button id="nameSubmitButton" onclick="submitName()">OK</button>
</form>
```

The input of type submit has been replaced by a button, and its `onclick` method retrieves the entered text, and sends it with a call to `fetch`:

```
const username = document.getElementById('nameField').value;

fetch('username', { method: 'POST', body: 'username=' + username })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The server response hasn't changed, but I now control the browser's behaviour when it gets the response. As a bonus, I can now directly POST to `username`, instead of using a hidden form element to hold the form's name, and reading the content of the hidden element on the server side to dispatch the request.